# Returning JSONP from Jersey

Tags: jersey, jsonp

I am currently using Jersey to return JSON. How do I return JSONP instead? For example, my current RESTful method is:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Order> getOrders() {
    return OrderRepository.getOrders();
}
```

I would like to deploy on Tomcat (don't want to require the use of GlassFish). My only dependencies on Jersey are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

What additional dependencies are needed? How will the code change?

Thanks.
Naresh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [JSONP](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/show/tags/jersey-1.9.1/jersey-1.9.1/jersey/samples/jsonp?rev=5806) example (especially the [ChangeList](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/tags/jersey-1.9.1/jersey-1.9.1/jersey/samples/jsonp/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/jsonp/resources/ChangeList.java?rev=5806) resource) in Jersey (you can download the whole project [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/samples/jsonp/1.9.1/jsonp-1.9.1-project.zip)).

What you basically need to do is something like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONWithPadding getOrders() {
    return new JSONWithPadding(new GenericEntity<List<Order>>(OrderRepository.getOrders()){});
}
```

Comment: Need to produce "application/javascript" and potentially add the callback param as per the example.

Answer (score 6):

It's important to modify the correct answer, as @s_t_e_v_e says. 
It should be something like this:

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/javascript"})
public JSONWithPadding getOrdersJSonP(@QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
    List<Order> orderList = OrderRepository.getOrders();
    return new JSONWithPadding(new GenericEntity<List<Order>>(orderList){}, 
                callback);
    }
```